# Mouse is not getting power from keyboard usb port on Win10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, mouse, razer-mouse

So I have this situation - only on Win10 for same hardware.

- Apple aluminum keyboard with two USB ports
- Razer Deathadder Elite mouse connected to one of this USB ports
- Win10 Pro

Mouse is not working (not getting power - since lights on mouse are not lit)
Win10 shows notification: "Not enough power on USB hub"

Same exact "connection scheme" works pretty well if I connect the keyboard to my Mac Laptop.
It even works when I go to BIOS settings of Win10 desktop, so I'm pretty sure there's some kind of configuration missing. Btw, simpler mouse work on Win10 - it's only the Deathadder which is not working, when connected to keyboards USB port.

Comment: just to verify, you are using the same cable for both mice, right? some cheap USB cables will be data-only or power-only. Its also possible that apple purposely disables it (would not surprise me).

Comment: well yes, the same... keyboard to PC/Laptop, mouse to keyboard. No ext cables or sth. As I wrote, the same setup works well in BIOS screen of same PC where Win10 is installed. From my perspective, Win10 is the only "not working" link in a chain

Comment: Are you plugging the mouse into a USB 2 or USB 3.2 Gen 1 port?

Comment: @Ramhound tried both USB 2 and USB 3.2 Gen1 -- same result. Actually saw this time (it disappears fast) note from Win10 that usb hub doesn't have power

Comment: Does the mouse use a lot of power? Macs can push a lot more power through the USB if specifically requested [first introduced to support iPad charging]. 2A vs 500mA. You can check this on a Mac from  menu > About this Mac > System report… > USB

Comment: @David - Are you using the cable that came with the mouse?

Comment: @Ramhound - yes.

Comment: Your question make no mention of receiving that notification

Comment: @Tetsujin - it says mouse requires 500mA out 500mA available. KB requires 20mA.

Comment: @Ramhound, I will edit the question. I didn't see that notification in time of writing the question.

Comment: Then it would appear that the pair between them need more than a standard port can supply.

Comment: @Tetsujin but how it works in BIOS settings screen then. On a same PC...

Comment: Maybe whatever 'smart' functionality which is eating 500mA [a massive consumption for a simple mouse] is not active at that point. I'd be asking Razer why on earth a mouse needs 500mA.